# Why cannot scala infer the type in the following example

Tags: scala

create a list

```
val l: List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
```

I can assign the head to a variable via

```
val t: Int = l.head
```

However, the following code fails

```
t = l.head
output:
Not found: t
```

Why is scala not able to infer the type of the head of the list as the type that the individual elements of the list have?

Comment: To my eyes this is a problem with undeclared variable, not with type inference. `val t = l.head` works fine and infers t to be `Int`

Comment: aahh .. got it. #PythonSpoiled

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where is the failing type inference?

Comment: yes, the question is unclear. I am completely new to scala and asked a bad question. However, I cannot delete it since other people have answered it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining variable you need to explicitly specify if it is mutable or not ([docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/taste-vars-data-types.html)):

> When you create a new variable in Scala, you declare whether the variable is immutable or mutable:

```scala
// immutable
val a = 0

// mutable
var b = 1
```

You are missing the `val`/`var` keyword, when you will add it type will be inferred:

```scala
val t = l.head // t is Int
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with undeclared variable, not with type inference.

`val t = l.head` works fine and infers `t` to be `Int`